# "Kernel died, restarting" ipython console in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I used spyder IDE for train a neural network but after installig Tensorflow and runnig my program show that error in ipython console.How to solve it?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is usually a problem related to your consuming all your RAM. Please try to run it in the Jupyter notebook to see if there's any difference.

Comment: That was solved,but now commin up with "" from google.protobuf.pyext import _message"

"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.""